# React Slick dots doesnt show

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, slick.js

I using slick slider but even i add dots:true i cant see dots on my screen.

My settings :

```
 const settings = {
    dots: true,
    customPaging: function (i) {
      return <LazyLoadImage src={productDetails.Images[i]} />; //I want image as a dot. (even i make it simple text its still doesnt show.)
    },
    dotsClass: "slick-dots slick-thumb",
    infinite: true,
    speed: 500,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
  };
```

I installed react-slick and slick-carousel too. I import css and Slider like :

```
import Slider from "react-slick";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
```

But it doesnt work. What can i do? Thanks for all responses!

Edit: I dont have `overflow:hidden`

Answer (score 0):

You pass just a string to an `src` attribute. Add a colon before it

```
<LazyLoadImage :src={productDetails.Images[i]}
```